# Why does my text file become unreadable on macOS after opening on WSL Vim?

Tags: unix, vim, encoding, windows-subsystem-for-linux, utf

I have a text file (`refs.bib`) in my Dropbox that was created using Vim on macOS. I open it on macOS Vim, the banner in the editor gives the details `unix | utf-8 | bib` and the file is legible. I do not make any changes and exit Vim.

I then open the file on Vim on my PC (through a terminal emulator on Windows Subsystem Linux), and the file is unintelligible (I see a repeated string of `^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`). The banner reads `unix | utf-8 | bib` (same as it did on macOS) except now next to the file name it says `[noeol]`. I close the file without making any changes.

Then when I open the file again on macOS, it's now unintelligible there too, and gives the same banner `unix | utf-8 | bib` now with the `[noeol]` next to the file name. The file continues to be unintelligible on WSL Vim as well.

I know `[noeol]` means there's no EOL at the end of file, but I didn't make any changes to the file. How can opening a file cause it to become unintelligible on both platforms? I thought this might be an encoding issue, but Vim never used anything other than `utf-8`.

Comment: Those symbols look like a series of null bytes. You could try xxd’ing it to see if the original data is there, but it’s possible the file is just corrupted